# What is the difference between Syntactic macros and Procedural macros?

Tags: rust, programming-languages

What is the difference between procedural macros and syntactic macros? Rust refers to its macro system as procedural, but I've seen language articles refer to a system like the rust macro system as syntactic macros. Syntactic macros would appear to have access to all or part of the AST when parsing them. Which appears to be what Rust has.

Comment: Macros are always syntactic so that doesn't make much sense to me. Unless they mean that you can have somewhat custom syntax in macros? Eh... Anyway that part's the same in all macros (kinda), the distinction Rust has is *declarative* v *procedural* macros. Declarative macros are defined using `macro_rules!` and they're simple (declarative) transformations, so they're mostly convenient helpers. Procedural macros are full blown Rust programs manipulating the token stream. Procedural macros are a lot more powerful because you have an entire programming language available.

Comment: Also because declarative macros process the AST, they have a few syntactic limitations which procedural macros don't as the compiler needs to be able to *create* an AST.

Comment: @Masklinn Macros access type information (not in Rust). Then they're not syntactic. But I agree this question needs clarity.

Answer (score 5):

Rust macros are syntactic; they work on the AST level.

What might be tripping you up in terminology is Rust has two flavors of macros that differ in how they are written and how they can be used. There are *declarative* macros (also called "macros by example") that are created by invocations of `macro_rules!`. And there are *procedural* macros, which are written as functions that handle `TokenStream`s as input and output (can be used as attributes, in derives, or like functions).

See also:

- [Macros](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-06-macros.html) in the Rust Book
- [Procedural Macros](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/procedural-macros.html) and [Macros by Example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/macros-by-example.html) in the Rust Reference

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be the root of the confusion.